# How to print Json encoded messages using Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a `DataSet[Row]` where each row is JSON string. I want to just print the JSON stream or count the JSON stream per batch.

Here is my code so far

```scala
val ds = sparkSession.readStream()
               .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",bootstrapServers"))
               .option("subscribe", topicName)
               .option("checkpointLocation", hdfsCheckPointDir)
               .load();

val ds1 = ds.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema) as 'payload)
val ds2 = ds1.select($"payload.info")
val query = ds2.writeStream.outputMode("append").queryName("table").format("memory").start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

```sql
select * from table; --  don't see anything and there are no errors. However when I run my Kafka consumer separately (independent ofSpark I can see the data)
```

My question really is what do I need to do just print the data I am receiving from Kafka using Structured Streaming? The messages in Kafka are JSON encoded strings so I am converting JSON encoded strings to some struct and eventually to a dataset. I am using Spark 2.1.0

Comment: Are you also discussing it on Spark users mailing list (with TD)? Trying to find out how different the two use cases are.

Comment: Hi! Yes but we haven't concluded that conversion. I am just trying to print data using structured streaming and I am having a hard time with that :(

Comment: I have also tried `val query = ds.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()` but that didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame as SparkDataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import *


# {"name":"jimyag","age":12,"ip":"111.11.1.1"}
# nc -l p 9999

spark:SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("readJSONData").getOrCreate()

lines:SparkDataFrame = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 9999).load()

jsons = lines.select(from_json(col("value"), "name STRING, age INT, ip STRING").alias("data")).select("data.*")

jsons.writeStream.format("console").start().awaitTermination()

# print
# +------+---+----------+
# |  name|age|        ip|
# +------+---+----------+
# |jimyag| 12|111.11.1.1|
# +------+---+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val ds1 = ds.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema) as payload).select($"payload.*")
```

That will print your data on the console.

```
ds1.writeStream.format("console").option("truncate", "false").start().awaitTermination()
```

Always use something like `awaitTermination()` or `thread.Sleep(time in seconds)` in these type of situations.